# Value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no member 'uid' problem

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am a newbie in Swift, learning from building a social media app following a tutorial of Kasey Schlaudt on youtube. When I write this line `KeychainWrapper.standard.set((user?.uid)!, forKey: "KEY_UID")` at minutes 36:11 if this video: https://youtu.be/gBB5tnAzjjo?t=2171 I get this error —> Value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no member 'uid'. Any suggestions on why this might be happening?
This is my code so far:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import SwiftKeychainWrapper

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var UserImageView: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @IBAction func signInPress(_ sender: Any) {
        if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text {
            
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    //Create account
                } else {
                    KeychainWrapper.standard.set((user?.uid)!, forKey: "KEY_UID")
                }
        }
    }

    }

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

The API documentation for [createUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#createuserwithemail:password:completion:) says that it provides an [AuthDataResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/AuthDataResult) object as the result.  As you can see from link, it doesn't have a `uid` property.  You will want to use its `user` property to get a [User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/User) object that does have a `uid`.

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
    if error != nil {
        //Create account
    } else {
        KeychainWrapper.standard.set((result?.user.uid)!, forKey: "KEY_UID")
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for linking to the product's documentation, which is much more likely to be up to date than a 3 year old youtube tutorial. 